# I want to write a PL/SQL script to query index statistics data and update tracking entries

Tags: oracle-xe

I have created a table:
INDEX_SIZE_TRACKING with the following attributes:

- Index Name: name of the index. Type: VARCHAR(255). This is the primary key of
  the table.
- Allocated Space: the memory space (in bytes) allocated to the index. Type:
  NUMBER
- Used Space: the memory space used by the index. Type: NUMBER
- Last Update: the time when index details are updated to this table. Type:
  VARCHAR(255)

I want to write a PL/SQL script to query index statistics data and update tracking
entries in the INDEX_SIZE_TRACKING table. If there is no existing entry for the
index, create a new one; otherwise, update the existing one.
Can I please have a PL/SQL statement that can do this in oracle XE?
Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle limits identifier names to 30 characters, doesn't it? VARCHAR(255) seems an unusual choice.

I'm pretty sure the dbms_space package has what you need to get the allocated and used space.

Last update is going to be a date. Why on earth would you use VARCHAR(255) for that?